# How can particles be emitted from particles?

Tags: particles

In a scene with two particle system configured as boids and boids brain set to fight, one swarm attacks the other. I would like to emit child particles as lines (laser or something) to visualize some fighting action.

I couldn't find a way to setup the line emitting particle system, either they are created from the plane or further cones will be added.

Is there a way to do this as I saw on a [firework animation tutorial](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/402-firework-with-particles-in-blender-263.html) but I didn't get the trick?

Blend file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/fightingboids)

[image]

At blendersushi [blog](http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/2013/07/update-blender-268-particles-use.html) the author says:

> PARTICLE INSTANCE MODIFIER > PARTICLES
> With this stacking thing, we can now pretty much emit Particles from emitted Particles, > if you know how to set it up. Not very obvious, but basically you Instance some meshes > (using Instance Modifier) and then add Particle System to the object with Instance > Modifier.
>
> Make sure you have "Use Modifier Stack" turned on.

But I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is, you use the particle instance modifier on one particle system, and the particle system is recognized as one object, so it can then be emitted from itself.

1. Create a baseObject (that will be emitting the particles that emit the particles).
2. Create a ps1Object (it will be the object that is emitted in the first particle system)
3. Give the baseObject a particle system.
4. Select the ps1Object, and give it a particle instance modifier. In the object tab, select baseObject. Make sure to reset the location of the ps1Object, so it looks like it's emitting from the baseObject.
5. Give the ps1Object a particle system and check Use Modifier Stack in the Emission tab.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [Reactor Particles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Physics/Particles/Types) are no longer supported :-/ So you can't get particles to emit particles, as such.

The "trick" that he used to make the fireworks is that particles get emitted from faces, but those faces might move while particles are being emitted. He used a modifier to break the faces of the sphere into pieces. Those pieces happen to be driven by a particle system, but the particles aren't emitting particles. The particles are driving the motion of the faces, and the faces are emitting particles.

In short, this "solution" solves a very specific problem, and I don't think it will be able to do what you want it to do.