# Why have reactor particles been deprecated since blender 2.5?

Tags: particles

my blender version is 2.70.
I've come to a situation where I'm in serious need of reactor particles but I've discovered that they've been deprecated since version 2.5x & I can't find any good solution to that.

Now I'm wondering: How can reactor particles be used in 2.70?

Comment: Simple! get version 2.5!

Comment: Do you mean halo particle?

Comment: You can download older versions of blender here: http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to get a lower version of blender, & I read the link, but is there an example of how to do that with billboards? say I want to make the billboards emit particles on death. What could I do?