# is there a way, how to use a object with a hair particle system to be emitted by another hair particle system?

Tags: particles

I want to make a tree, so I made a tree and a plane for leafs and then used the particle system to emit leafs from the tree. That worked, but it didn't have enough branches and I am limited on faces per tree, so I made a branch with leafs (the same way: branch hair particle system with leafs as object), to emit it together with the leafs, but now I can't emit it with the leafs, all I get is a stick sticking from the trunk. can I somehow apply it or something, so that it would emit together?

Comment: is something like this useful? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles