# Using a hair particle system to emit an object that already has a duplivert?

Tags: particles

Apparantly it isn't possible to emit another particle from an existing particle system. i.e a nested particle system.

However is a possible work around to emit an object that already has a duplivert of another object?

It's been suggested that is a duplicate of another [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles) however this isn't connected to a particle system emitting another particle system. This is specifically about a particle system emitting an object that has a duplivert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can particles be emitted from particles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, in any case I've just worked a work around. A nested duplivert seems to be closest I can get. It doesn't involve particles however. But for me it had the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. I thought your problem could be solved with the particle instance modifier. Do you have a solution now? If yes, would you mind sharing it as an answer?

Comment: Hi Leander, no worries, I'm not sure I've got a definitive answer to my question. As my "solution" is actually a work around that doesn't use particles at all, this being the case it isn't as flexible as particle based solution where a lot of settings can be configured.

Comment: might be possible with animation nodes, though wont be easy.