# Particles emitting from particles. Is it possible?

Tags: particles

I am relatively new in the world of Blender, which I have started using as a scientist to make schematics for publications.

I am currently struggling in making a particle emitting from a particle system and use that as a particle.

Essentially what I want to do is make a sphere with spheres emitted from the vertices
[image: image 1] and I want these spheres to have hairs on top as in image below:
[image: image 2]

In the latter case, I had to manually position the smaller spheres on the big sphere surface and manually delete half on the emitting hairs. I really don't want to do it manually all the time lol. Do you guys know how to do it easily?

Comment: Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles

Comment: Have you considered using [Dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=duplivert) to place the smaller spheres, and using a particle system on the spheres being placed by Dupivert?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am having a look at your link kim. Although, How would I do it on a sphere? In the guide they use a simple circle and I can't follow it.

Comment: I managed to do it using Dupliverts! Thank you all!