# Leaves not showing up on my Tree (particle Systems)in Blender 2.79

Tags: particles

I am new to Blender and I tried to make a tree model. I created a basic tree structure and then aimed to distribute leaves on it. I tried to do this by creating a branch which I distributed leaves on (as particles). The goal was to *then* use these branches as particles for my tree. However, in doing so: while the branches appear on the tree as particles, the leaves are not appearing. I do not understand what the reason for this might be, I thought it might have to do with overlapping particle systems but I am unsure about how to approach that problem; other than that, I have tried disabling subsurf modifier, putting particle system above in priority (in modifiers tab for branch) but this hasn't worked.

Vertex groups have been created to deal with distribution of particles.

The particles are themselves taken as groups. 'Leaves' in case of the branch and 'branches' group in case of the tree. (not to be confused with vertex groups)

Tree Structure

[image: Tree Structure]

Branches

[image: Branches]

Branch Property Tab p1

[image: Branch Property]

Branch Property Tab p2

[image: Br Prop 2]

Branch Modifier

[image: Modifier Tab]

Tree after using branches as particles

[image: Tree after using branches as particles]

Tree Modifiers

[image: Tree Modifiers]

Comment: "The trick is, you use the particle instance modifier on one particle system, and the particle system is recognized as one object, so it can then be emitted from itself" :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can particles be emitted from particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles)