# Make particles emit exponentially quickly

Tags: particles

I am trying to make an animation where particles seem like they are multiplying, and the easiest way I could think of was to have the emitter emit particles at an increasing rate, rather than linearly which is what it does by default. I'm not sure this is possible, but if it is someone please tell me.

Another way I could think of to do this was to have the first generation of particles emit the second generation of particles, which would then emit the third generation, but I couldn't find a documentation of this that would work for me. I tried this [How can particles be emitted from particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles) but that didn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this thread is still active; but I solved the same (or similar issue) by simply animating the MAX distance of the force that affected the particles. So the force was slowly growing over the "emitter" box that holds the particles. That was happening off-screen in my case.

[image: Simple setup of an animated MAX value]

Answer (score 0):

i would solve it by setting a keyframe in the ammount of particles and one at the end of the animation.
Then in the Graph Editor you can change the curve to match your need or use a preset by pressing T and then select if you need exponential, quadratic, etc...

Comment: How would I add a keyframe for the amount of particles. It doesn't seem to be in the particle menu or the add keyframe menu.

Comment: Are you using hair or emission particles?

Comment: emission particles

Comment: You cannot emit particles from other particles. You say you cannot add keyframe to the particles ammount (I can which is odd). Then you could try it with children instead of the base. Would me more optimized too